# Excel hangs at exit after running RDVBA tests

Tags: excel, vba, rubberduck

The following example contains three VBA modules: two classes and one regular. After I run RubberDuck VBA tests and then try to close Excel, Excel hangs while actively using the CPU. Running the tests once does not reproduce this issue every time, but when I do at least two runs, it seems that the issue is reproduced every time.

---

RDVBA Version 2.5.2.5871
OS: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0, x64

**Test environment 1:**
Host Product: Microsoft Office XP x86
Host Version: 10.0.6501
Host Executable: EXCEL.EXE

**Test environment 2:**
Host Product: Microsoft Office 2016 x64
Host Version: 16.0.4266.1001
Host Executable: EXCEL.EXE

---

**ModuleTests.bas**

```vb
'@TestModule
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

Private Assert As Rubberduck.PermissiveAssertClass

#Const USE_ASSERT_OBJECT = True

'@ModuleInitialize
Private Sub ModuleInitialize()
    Set Assert = New Rubberduck.PermissiveAssertClass
End Sub

'@ModuleCleanup
Private Sub ModuleCleanup()
    Set Assert = Nothing
    Debug.Print CStr(Timer()) & ": Assert = Nothing"
End Sub

'@TestMethod("Factory")
Private Sub ztcCreate_VerifiesDefaultManager()
    Dim dbm As Class2
    Set dbm = Class2.Create(ThisWorkbook.Path)
    #If USE_ASSERT_OBJECT Then
        Assert.IsNotNothing dbm
    #Else
        Assert.IsTrue Not dbm Is Nothing
    #End If
End Sub
```

**Class1.cls**

```vb
'@PredeclaredId
Option Explicit

Public Function Create(Optional ByVal DefaultPath As String = vbNullString) As Class1
    Dim Instance As Class1
    Set Instance = New Class1
    Set Create = Instance
End Function

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Debug.Print CStr(Timer()) & ": Class1 Class_Terminate"
End Sub
```

**Class2.cls**

```vb
'@PredeclaredId
Option Explicit

Private Type TClass2
    DllMan As Class1
End Type
Private this As TClass2

'@DefaultMember
Public Function Create(ByVal DllPath As String) As Class2
    Dim Instance As Class2
    Set Instance = New Class2
    Instance.Init DllPath
    Set Create = Instance
End Function

Friend Sub Init(ByVal DllPath As String)
    Dim FileNames As Variant
    Set this.DllMan = Class1.Create(DllPath)
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Debug.Print CStr(Timer()) & ": Class2 Class_Terminate"
End Sub
```

Comment: RubberDuck is all but reliable in my experience. Best way to break your code. (sorry to the author who is often around here). 
I just enable it when I need to indent a poorly written project I am hired to fix.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez It has certain issues, sure, but I use it all the time. Not all of its functionality, but it is a great dev aid for VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That flickering that you are seeing when Excel is hanging is basically Excel trying to clear an object from memory but failing. I know that for sure because the same thing happens if inside a userform there is a private custom class that doesn't get set to `Nothing` before the form unloads.

If you add this code to your `Class2`:

```
Friend Sub Clear()
    Set this.DllMan = Nothing
End Sub
```

and then update this:

```
Assert.IsNotNothing dbm
```

to this:

```
Assert.IsNotNothing dbm
dbm.Clear
```

inside the test method then the issue is gone.

Moreover, if I update the test method:

```
'@TestMethod("Factory")
Private Sub ztcCreate_VerifiesDefaultManager()
    Dim dbm As Class2
    Set dbm = Class2.Create(ThisWorkbook.Path)
    #If USE_ASSERT_OBJECT Then
        Assert.IsNotNothing dbm
        Debug.Print "Before Clear"
        dbm.Clear
        Debug.Print "After Clear"
    #Else
        Assert.IsTrue Not dbm Is Nothing
    #End If
    Debug.Print "After Test"
End Sub
```

then after I run the test I get this in the Immediate window:
[image: image1]

and only after about 7 seconds I get the last line:
[image: image2]

This suggests to me that the `Assert.IsNotNothing` holds on to the reference for longer than it should.

**Edit #1**

Removing the `Clear` method and changing the Terminate event for Class2 to this:

```
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set this.DllMan = Nothing
    Debug.Print CStr(Timer()) & ": Class2 Class_Terminate"
End Sub
```

seems to also solve the issue. The only difference is that now both classes get delayed, as expected. So, the delay itself doesn't seem to be an issue.

Comment: Class1 terminates properly, but, as you mentioned, Assert still delays the termination of Class2. However, it appears that now (with your suggestion) Excel terminates properly nevertheless.

Comment: @PChemGuy Added a small edit to the answer. Weird stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I have amended the original code and ran a few more experiments exposing some odd behavior as illustrated below. While the nature of the problem is still unclear and appears to be associated with RDVBA (I think I now have sufficient evidence to create an RDVBA issue), I have narrowed down the problem and found a workaround.

In short, I originally had this test `Assert.IsNotNothing dbm`, and with instrumented code, I observed odd termination timing/sequence. The amended code includes a conditional compilation structure for illustrative purposes. When `Assert.IsTrue Not dbm Is Nothing` construct is selected instead, both symptoms and the issue are gone.